# Is it possible to find the $n$th digit of $\pi$ (in base $10$)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it possible that there exists some function $f:\mathbb N_1\to \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, where $$f(1)=\color{red}1, f(2)=\color{red}4, f(3)=\color{red}1, f(4)=\color{red}5, f(5)=\color{red}9, f(6)=\color{red}2, \ldots \quad ?$$

I know that such a function, if it exists, cannot be a polynomial, since all polynomials are finite-dimensional, whereas the sequence containing the digits of $\pi$ has infinitely many elements, but could it be that there is some function (even if we cannot explicitly state it) which gives the $n$th  term of the sequence containing the digits of $\pi$?

If this is true, and such a function *does* exist, can the same be said for all transcendental numbers?

---

Edit: to be absolutely clear, I **am** looking for the explicit function $f$ such that $f(n)$ is the $n$th digit of $\pi$ (in base $10$).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula

Comment: There's nothing wrong with defining a function using words, $f(n) = n$th digit of $\pi$. So certainly there is a function for what you want. Perhaps you're asking for a formula -- but then again you mentioned you don't mind whether we can "explicitly state it". So it's not clear what you're after.

Comment: The function certainly exists. The problem is computing it.

Comment: @ajotatxe How do we know that such a function exists?

Comment: @alexqwx You are defining it in your question: $f(n)$ is the $n$th digit of $\pi$.

Comment: If you believe that we are free to define the values of a function $\mathbb{N} \to \{ 0, \dots , 9 \}$, then you already believe the function exists. In fact, your belief in the function is implicit in the first indented equations. Just because you can't list the function's values (either because you don't know them or you don't have enough time) doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Joshua Ciappara What I mean be a function, in this case, is a mapping which consists of finitely-many elementary functions.

Comment: @alexqwx: If appropriate, you should explain what you want to use such an answer for; you might have better luck finding that than trying to explain how you want an answer to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course that function exists. You have just defined it.

If you want a symbolic-looking *expression* for your function, then how about

$$ f(n) = \lfloor 10^n\pi \rfloor \bmod 10 $$

---

The larger point, however, seems to be that you're using the word "function" in a much narrower sense than (contemporary) mathematics does. It looks like you want a "function" to be a symbolic expression, but in mathematics a function is simply *anything* which associates one and only one output value for each input value in its domain. It is immaterial *how* this association is done, as long as we're sure that it gives an output for every input, and that the output depends *only* on what the input is.

If you like set-theoretic formalizations, then a function $X\to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are sets, means a set of pairs with the first component being a member of $X$ and the second component being a member of $Y$ (that is, $f\subset X\times Y$), satisfying the conditions that:

- for every $x\in X$ there is an $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in f$ *(every input has an output)*.
- for every $x,y,z$, if $(x,y)\in f$ and $z\ne y$, then $(x,z)\notin f$ *(there is only one output for each input)*.

It doesn't where we got the set from. In your case the function $f:\mathbb N\to\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ is
$$ f = \{ (n,d) \mid \text{The }n^{\text{th}}\text{ decimal of }\pi\text{ is }d\} $$
a perfectly cromulent function.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly means explicit? For a given $n$, there is certainly an algorithm that computes the $n$'th digit of $\pi$.

But the answer is *no* if you ask about some other real numbers. There are [non-computable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) that encode the halting problem, for example. There is no chance to have an algorithm computing the digits of some numbers in general -- and hence not any reasonable "formula" composed of common basic operations for those numbers.